# Testing for non-strict inequality with np.testing

Tags: python, numpy, testing

`np.testing.assert_array_less()` tests for strict inequality:

```
In [1]: np.testing.assert_array_less(1., 1.)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ea8ee0b762c3> in <module>()
----> 1 np.testing.assert_array_less(1., 1.)

AssertionError: 
Arrays are not less-ordered
```

apparently there is no parameter to test for non-strict inequality.

How would one test this by still relying on np.testing for its interpretable error messages? (I'd like to avoid `assert (a <= b).all()`)

Answer (score 3):

As you note, apparently non-strict inequality is not among the defined test cases in `numpy.testing`. Also, there is no *documented* way to extend `numpy.testing` with more test cases.

Looking at the source, it is clear that it is possible to roll your own test cases, using `assert_array_compare`:

```
import operator

def assert_array_less_equal(x, y, err_msg='', verbose=True):
    from numpy.testing import assert_array_compare
    __tracebackhide__ = True  # Hide traceback for py.test
    assert_array_compare(operator.__le__, x, y, err_msg=err_msg,
                         verbose=verbose,
                         header='Arrays are not equal or less-ordered')

>>> assert_array_less_equal(1., 1.)
>>> assert_array_less_equal(1.1, 1.)
.
.
.
AssertionError: 
Arrays are not equal or less-ordered

(mismatch 100.0%)
 x: array(1.1)
 y: array(1.)
```

However, as stated, `assert_array_compare` is not documented, but rather a helper function within `numpy.testing`. Therefore I guess it can be subject to changes and updates without any notification  when `numpy` is updated. This could potentially, silently break your code.